# How should a global (module) object be created in a Python function?

Tags: python, url, import, global, local

I am trying to write a function to "import" a Python module from a URL (as an experiment -- there are, of course, security concerns with such an approach). In doing so, I am attempting to create the module object in the function and then to modify it with the downloaded code of the remote module. I think this is working, but I am having difficulty making this module usable outside of the function.

How can I make the module I "import" available outside of the "importing" function?

```
import sys
import urllib
import imp

def smuggle(URL = None, As  = None):
    exec("global " + As)
    moduleLocalName = As
    moduleString    = urllib.urlopen(URL).read()
    if moduleLocalName is None:
        exec moduleString in globals()
    else:        
        exec(moduleLocalName + " = imp.new_module(\"" + moduleLocalName + "\")")
        exec moduleString in globals()[moduleLocalName].__dict__

smuggle(URL = "https://cdn.rawgit.com/wdbm/shijian/master/shijian.py", As = "shijianTest")
alpha = shijianTest.Clock(name = "alpha")
alpha.printout()
```

Comment: Have you considered saving it into the hard drive and then inserting it to the PYTHONPATH (using `sys.path.insert()`)?

Comment: [Igor Hatarist](http://stackoverflow.com/users/974317/igor-hatarist) Thanks for the suggestion. That approach could indeed work, but for the purposes of this experiment, I'm trying to use the remote resource using only volatile memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also a thing to consider:

Perhaps, just return a module and use it where needed?

```
# hello.py
def world():
    print 'hello world!'
```

```
# smuggle.py
def smuggle(url, name):
    code = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    module = imp.new_module(name)
    exec code in module.__dict__
    return module

hello = smuggle("http://127.0.0.1:1234/hello.py", "hello")
hello.world()
# prints out "hello world!"
```

You could also create a global dictionary of smuggled modules and put the imported modules there, later addressing it like `smuggled['hello'].world()`.

Comment: Ah, that's a sensible approach. Thank you very much for your help on this.